# Python read a file replace a string in a word

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to read a file with below data

```
Et1, Arista2, Ethernet1
Et2, Arista2, Ethernet2
Ma1, Arista2, Management1
```

I need to read the file replace `Et` with `Ethernet` and `Ma` with `Management`. At the end of them the digit should be the same. The actual output should be as follows

```
Ethernet1, Arista2, Ethernet1
Ethernet2, Arista2, Ethernet2
Management1, Arista2, Management1
```

I tried a code with Regular expressions, I am able to get to the point I can parse all `Et1`, `Et2` and `Ma1`. But unable to replace them.

```
import re
with open('test.txt','r') as fin:
       for line in fin:
       data = re.findall(r'\A[A-Z][a-z]\Z\d[0-9]*', line)
       print(data)
```

The output looks like this..

```
['Et1'] 
['Et2'] 
['Ma1']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

#to avoid compile in each iteration
re_et = re.compile(r'^Et(\d+),')
re_ma = re.compile(r'^Ma(\d+),')

with open('test.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        data = re_et.sub('Ethernet\g<1>,', line.strip())
        data = re_ma.sub('Management\g<1>,', data)
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This example follows Joseph Farah's suggestion

```
    import csv
    file_name = 'data.csv'
    output_file_name = "corrected_data.csv"

    data = []
    with open(file_name, "rb") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)

    corrected_data = []
    for row in data:
        tmp_row = []
        for col in row:
            if 'Et' in col and not "Ethernet" in col:
                col = col.replace("Et", "Ethernet")
            elif 'Ma' in col and not "Management" in col:
                col = col.replace("Ma", "Management")
            tmp_row.append(col)
        corrected_data.append(tmp_row)

    with open(output_file_name, "wb") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in corrected_data:
            writer.writerow(row)        

    print data
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you should take:

1. Read each line in the file
2. Separate each line into smaller list items using the comments as delimiters
3. Use `str.replace()` to replace the characters with the words you want; keep in mind that anything that says "Et" (including the beginning of the word "ethernet") will be replaced, so remember to account for that. Same goes for Ma and Management.
4. Roll it back into one big list and put it back in the file with `file.write()`. You may have to overwrite the original file.